# How do I create a stacked graph of HTTP codes in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm sending HTTP logs into Kibana, and the response code (200, 401, 500, etc) are correctly parsed out of them as a field. I'd like a time-series chart with the count of each code shown as bars stacked on top of each other in each interval, in different colors. This should help see if there are suddenly more 500 errors, for example.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create such a chart in Kibana. Is this possible?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*This is a Kibana 3 answer, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26471825/1004046) if you are using Kibana 4 or 5*

## Kibana 3

If I do not misunderstand your question what you need is:

- Define your queries. If you want a bar per response type you need to define one query per response. You have to define a query `field: <value>` for filtering the exact value. For instance, you can have queries like:

[image: Defining the queries]

- Create an Histogram.
- Configure the Histogram with:

  - Queries: You can select all the queries, or select only a few that the ones that you wrote in the first place.

[image: Queries]

- Panel: You can put a configuration like this. You can set a custom interval to group your logs, you stack the values as individual (makes more sense I think, when you put the mouse over the graph will show the correct value and not the stacked one...). You can experiment a bit with the options.

[image: Panels]

The final result will be something like:

[image: Final result]

Comment: This works for a limited number of codes, what if you have values that are not predefined constants?

Comment: @Brimstedt At the moment, it is not possible to do it with Kibana

Comment: Can you save this as part of the panel?

Comment: The reason the stacked graph shows up on the image above is because multiple query fields are being used. 
I would like to save the panel so that it always shows the stacked graph even if my query field is empty.

Comment: @Patrick It is not possible with Kibana3, but I think it is possible with Kibana4 now. I'll edit the answer when I have some time to do it :D

Comment: Thanks @Pigueiras! I tried Kibana 4 but it looks like I need to update to ES beta which I think I shouldn't do with the production cluster yet. Looks like I'll have to wait

Answer (score 67):

*This is a Kibana 4/5 answer, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22055304/1004046) if you are using Kibana 3*

## Kibana 4/5

At the moment of writing, the only version available for Kibana 4 is *beta1*, so these screenshots might be different in future versions of Kibana. I will try to keep them updated, if relevant changes are applied.

Kibana 4 (and 5) provides some features that the previous version didn't have. For example, now we can build panels using the aggregations that were available in ES since version 1.0.

To build a stacked graph of HTTP codes (or other field), you have to:

- Click on the *Visualize* tab. This tab allows you to build panels that you can put afterwards in a dashboard.

[image: Visualize tab]

- Then you have to select that you want to create the visualization making a new search (or using an existing one, if you played before in the *Discover* tab. You have to select an existing index that you previously configured.

[image: Create a visualization from a search]

- Once you selected your index, you have to select the type of panel that you want. In this case, we will select a *Vertical bar chart*.

[image: Type of chart selection]

- Next we will find a beautiful page with a graph on the right part and a panel with different options. This panel will let us to define a query to plot our data. Basically, what we want to plot in the Y axis is a count of documents (by default is the one that is selected).

[image: Count of documents in the Y axis]

- Then we add a new aggregation, first we want a total count of documents distributed on time and then we want to split this total with the different existing codes. Furthermore, the first aggregation will be per timestamp and the second one per codes. You want to plot the timestamp on the X axis (select *X axis*) and you want to split the bars into the different codes (select *Split bars*). Your final configuration should be something like this:

[image: Final configuration]

- After applying, the final result should be something like this.

[image: Final plot]

- You can play with the interval, if you want to aggregate data for more or less time (there are several options like hourly, daily, monthly ...). Remember to change the timespan on the top, if you want to see more data, because this graph is limited by that timestamp.

Comment: Kibana 4 crashes when I use @timestamp. Can you tell me the format and mapping of your timestamp?

Comment: "@timestamp": {
  "format": "dateOptionalTime",
  "type": "date"
} @AliClarke

Comment: Can I present the error rate? E.g., number of internal error/ number of all record.

Comment: @okwap Not possible at the moment. To do that you would need the [pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-pipeline.html), present in ES2.0 and [this Kibana issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4584) in Github closed (it's not even in the road map though :()

Answer (score 0):

Kibana 3

For bar per response type you want to write one query per response. You had not defined a query field:  for filtering. For example, you can have queries like:

[image: Filtering]

Then you will get result like this.

[image: Result image]